# Get a value of an anonymous object in an anonymous method

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to write a general method like:

```
protected async Task<ResultModel<TU>> GetEntityByIdAsync<TU, TKey>(TKey id) where TU : class
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _db.Set<TU>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x =>
                x.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(???).ToString() == id.ToString());
            return result.ToResultModel();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error($"Error In GetEntityByIdAsync {typeof(TU).Name}. Error: {ex}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

but I cannot figure it out what should I put in `GetValue(???)`.
any help?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write your own version of the `Find` method that already does this for you. In particular because what you are doing will not work with Entity Framrwork.

Comment: `GetValue` expects the instance for which you want to get the properties value. So you probably need `GetValue(x)`.

Comment: how 'Find' can solve my problem?

Comment: @ HimBromBeere bingo! the answer is correct thanks

Comment: To get the anonymouse, implement an anonycat... ;)

Comment: @HimBromBeere Please don't suggest that for an Entity Framework query like this. Doing this forces EF to load an entire table into memory.

Comment: @DavidG True, I just answered the "what to provide to `GetValue`"-part. I never stated it makes sense or is a good idea.

Comment: What DavidG is saying that the same is achieved with `_db.Set<TU>().Find(id)` (or `FindAsync`). In other words, XY problem. Even if you fix the concrete problem, it would be super inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can get it working as you are trying to do, what you will find is that Entity Framework Core is not able to parse the reflection code, meaning it will run the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` in memory. So if you have a table with 1000 rows, all of those rows will be extracted from the database and filtered there. There's a few solutions:

1. Use the [DbSet.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?view=efcore-2.1) method, this looks like it will do exactly what you are trying to achieve. For example:

   ```
   var entity = await _db.Set<TU>().FindAsync(id)
   ```
2. Make your entities implement a common interface, for example:

   ```
   public interface IEntity
   {
       int Id { get; }
   }
   ```

   Meaning your entities will look something like this:

   ```
   public class SomeEntity : IEntity
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And finally your method now looks a lot simpler:

   ```
   protected async Task<ResultModel<TU>> GetEntityByIdAsync<TU, TKey>(TKey id)
       where TU : IEntity
   {
       return await _db.Set<TU>.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
   }
   ```
3. Build up an expression manually. This is a lot more involved and I'm not going to show how to do it as it's almost certainly not needed in this situation.

Comment: "meaning it will run the FirstOrDefaultAsync in memory" No, it'll just throw an exception.  You could explicitly load the data into memory to prevent EF from trying to run it at all though (but you shouldn't do that, obviously).

Comment: @Servy Not true I'm afraid. This is EF Core which means it silently fails to translate the expression and evaluates locally. It will spit out a warning message to debug if you keep your eye out though, something like *The expression could not be translated and will be evaluated locally*

Comment: @Servy Side note, it's possible to tell EF Core to throw when it encounters these by using [`ConfigureWarnings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.configurewarnings?view=efcore-2.1) and [`RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.relationaleventid.queryclientevaluationwarning?view=efcore-2.1).